# Ninject different behaviour between Kernel.Get and Constructor Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

What do I have:

```
public interface IBla
{
}

public class Bla1 : IBla
{
}

public class Bla : IBla
{
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly IBla[] _array;

    public Consumer(IBla[] array)
    {
        _array = array;
    }
}

public static class NinjectExtensions
{
      public class BindListExpression<TElement>
      {
          private readonly IKernel _kernel;
          private readonly List<Type> _types = new List<Type>();

          public BindListExpression(IKernel kernel)
          {
              _kernel = kernel;
          }

          public BindListExpression<TElement> ImplementedBy<T>() where T : TElement
          {
              var type = typeof(T);

              _kernel.Bind<T>().To(type);
              _types.Add(type);

              return this;
          }

          public void Bind()
          {
              Func<TElement[]> createObjects = () =>
              {
                  var sourceArray = new TElement[_types.Count];
                  for (var i = 0; i < _types.Count; i++)
                  {
                      var value = _kernel.Get(_types[i]);
                      sourceArray[i] = (TElement)value;
                  }
                  return sourceArray;
              };

              _kernel.Bind<TElement[]>().ToMethod(x => createObjects().ToArray());
              _kernel.Bind<List<TElement>>().ToMethod(x => (createObjects().ToList()));
              _kernel.Bind<IEnumerable<TElement>>().ToMethod(x => createObjects().ToList());
          }
      }
      public static BindListExpression<T> ListOf<T>(this IKernel kernel)
      {
          return new BindListExpression<T>(kernel);
      }
  }
```

Usage:

```
// Binds items in the given order as a list (Ninject does not guarantee the given order so I use this mechanism).
kernel.ListOf<IBla>()
    .ImplementedBy<Bla1>()
    .ImplementedBy<Bla>()
    .Bind();

var consumer = kernel.Get<Consumer>(); // result: consumer._array is empty?! --> what is imo wrong
var array = kernel.Get<IBla[]>(); // result: Bla1, Bla --> correct
```

Why doesn't Ninject produce the same result between a `Get<IBla[]>()` and constructor with a parameter `IBla[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With constructor injection, ninject translates the ctor parameter `IBla[]` to a `IResolutionRoot.GetAll<IBla>().ToArray()`. That's how support for multi-injection is implemented. So it's not possible for a ctor-request to result in a `IResolutionRoot.Get<IBla[]>()` - but it's still something you can do manually.

This is true for all collection-types which ninject translates to multi-injection (AFAIR array, `IList`, `IEnumerable`, but not `ICollection`).

I'd recommend using another collection interface (like `ICollection`) or collection implementation as constructor parameter. This will result in consistent behavior for ctor-injection and `IResolutionRoot.Get` calls.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to disable mutli-injection support or list/array injection support? What I real want is to bind a list of items where the given order is used for the resolution of that binded list. Ninject does not guarantee the right order when you resolve a list/array.

Comment: You cannot disable it by changing [settings](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/INinjectSettings.cs). You could probably replace some [internal component](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Component-Extension-Points) but i would really not recommend to do it. So all that you can do is use injecting another collection type which is not detected as "multi injection" by ninject.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to bind array dependencies in a specific order. You just need to register them in `Ninject` like this.

```
_kernel.Bind<Bla1>().ToSelf();
_kernel.Bind<Bla>().ToSelf();
_kernel.Bind<IConsumer>().To<Consumer>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("array", 
        new IBla[] { 
            _kernel.Get<Bla1>(), 
            _kernel.Get<Bla>() 
        });
```