# Configuring Ninject to return a list of results

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I'm using Ninject to resolve dependencies and it's working swimmingly until now. In this example, I actually need a list of objects initialized based on data stored in my App.config.

However, Ninject keeps returning an empty list. The snippet below is an example of what I tried. I've included the constructors for the class hierarchy for some context.

```
public ServiceSchedulerBuilder(IList<ITextExportService> textExportServices)
{
    _textExportService = textExportServices;    
}

public TextExportService(IHotFolderManager hotFolder)
{
    _hotFolder = hotFolder;
}

public HotFolderManager(string baseFolderPath, string defaultFileSearchPattern)
{
    //Some IO
}

//In a Ninject AppModule...
Kernel.Bind<IList<ITextExportService>>().ToMethod(ctx => 
{ 
    var services = new List<ITextExportService>();

    foreach (var device in GetDevicesByEnvironment())
    {
        var service = ctx.Kernel.Get<ITextExportService>(new ConstructorArgument("hotFolder", ctx.Kernel.Get<IHotFolderManager>(
                                                                    new ConstructorArgument("baseFolderPath", device.Path),
                                                                    new ConstructorArgument("defaultFileSearchPattern", "*.jmf"))));

        services.Add(service);
    }
    return services;
});
```

I suspect this all stems from the fact that I don't explicitly have a binding registered for ITextExportService itself. But since the implementation is going to be dependent on data from App.config, I can't understand how I could register it and not just receive the same instance every time when I ask for a list of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related: [Ninject different behaviour between Kernel.Get and Constructor Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354716/ninject-different-behaviour-between-kernel-get-and-constructor-injection)
--> there's a mismatch with how ninject behaves when doing `kernel.Get<IList<T>>` and resolving an `IList<T>` parameter of a ctor.

So here it goes:

ninject's [multi injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection) feature takes priority here.  Whenever ninject encounters a request for `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>` or `T[]` (but AFAIR not `ICollection<T>`) it will translate it to a request to resolve all bindings (without condition or with a matching condition) for `T`.

Try to the following:

```
public interface INoMultiBindingList<T> : IList<T> { }

public class NoMultiBindingList<T> : List<T>, INoMultiBindingList<T> { }
```

with:

sbb    public ServiceSchedulerBuilder(INoMultiBindingList textExportServices)
    {
        textExportService = textExportServices;
    }

```
Kernel.Bind<INoMultiBindingList<ITextExportService>>().ToMethod(ctx => 
{ 
    var services = new NoMultiBindingList<ITextExportService>();

    foreach (var device in GetDevicesByEnvironment())
    {
        var service = ctx.Kernel.Get<ITextExportService>(new ConstructorArgument("hotFolder", ctx.Kernel.Get<IHotFolderManager>(
                                                                    new ConstructorArgument("baseFolderPath", device.Path),
                                                                    new ConstructorArgument("defaultFileSearchPattern", "*.jmf"))));

        services.Add(service);
    }
    return services;
});
```

Comment: Wow, very interesting. It works, though I have to use the concrete `NoMultiBindingList` because, as defined, it doesn't know how to convert from a NoMultibindingList to INoMultibindingList and Ninject is unhappy about it.

Comment: I made an edit to inherit from INoMultieBindingList<T> that resolved the issue.

Comment: @Killnine sorry, i forgot to add the interface `INoMultiBindingList<T>` to `NoMultiBindingList<T>` - that's why it didn't compile. I've adapted the code. EDIT: oops, should have reloaded the page before posting the comment ;-)