# Ninject - bind a List of types

Tags: c#, ninject

I am using `Ninject`. What I want to do is to map a `List` of type, And then inject it in a constructor of my class:

```
private readonly IList<IDispatchFilter> m_Filters;

public DispatchFilteringManager(IList<IDispatchFilter> filters)
{
    m_Filters = filters;
}
```

I have tried this binding:

```
Bind<IList<IDispatchFilter>>()
    .ToMethod(bindDecoyDispatchFilters)
    .InSingletonScope();

private IList<IDispatchFilter> bindDecoyDispatchFilters(IContext context)
{
    Bind<IDispatchFilter>().To<WindowsXpFilter>();

    IList<IDispatchFilter> result = context.Kernel.GetAll<IDispatchFilter>().ToList();

    return result;
}
```

But in my constructor I get an empty `List`.

I can't seen to find a solution for this simple task.

Comment: A `.ToMethod` binding most likely will execute the method in order to get the instance and because it happens on run-time when all bindings will have been finished, this line will be simply ignored: `Bind<IDispatchFilter>()`. You could move it to outer scope where Ninject can pick it up.

Comment: @Fabjan ok, i will try and update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Bind<IList<IDispatchFilter>>()
    .ToMethod(bindDecoyDispatchFilters)
    .InSingletonScope();

private IList<IDispatchFilter> bindDecoyDispatchFilters(IContext context)
{
    Bind<IDispatchFilter>().To<WindowsXpFilter>();
    ...
}
```

To:

```
Bind<IDispatchFilter>().To<WindowsXpFilter>();
Bind<IList<IDispatchFilter>>()
    .ToMethod(bindDecoyDispatchFilters)
    .InSingletonScope();

private IList<IDispatchFilter> bindDecoyDispatchFilters(IContext context)
{
    ...
}
```

Explanation:

A method that we use in `.ToMethod` binding for let's say `T` will be executed only when we call `container.Get<T>` and not before that.

When Ninject tries to resolve `IList<IDispatchFilter>>` in the `bindDecoyDispatchFilters` method it looks for all bindings for `IDispatchFilter` registered *before that* and finds none. Therefore the ctor parameter is resolved as an empty collection.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are receiving no items in your constructor is unfortunately due to the way Ninject's [Multi Injection works](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Multi-injection). Ninject's resolution of `IList<T>` seems to non-intuitively look for all (independently) registered `<T>` and inject them into your class taking `IList<T>`, instead of actually using the explicitly registered method for resolving `IList<T>`.

As a result, `bindDecoyDispatchFilters` (as bound by `.ToMethod(bindDecoyDispatchFilters)`) will never be called, as Ninject will instead resolve the `IList<T>` based on the registered types `T`. (This is easily tested - put a breakpoint, or `Assert.Fail()` inside the method - it isn't ever called).

So if

```
Bind<IDispatchFilter>().To<WindowsXpFilter>();
```

is the only `IDispatchFilter` which ever needs to be resolved in the `IList`, then you can drop the registration, and as per @Fabjan's, directly register  `Bind<IDispatchFilter>().To<WindowsXpFilter>();`. The multi injection will resolve this as a single element in the `IList<T>` passed to your constructor.

You can then remove the `IList<T>` binding altogether:

```
Bind<IList<IDispatchFilter>>() ... remove 
    .ToMethod(bindDecoyDispatchFilters)
    .InSingletonScope();
```

and also drop the `bindDecoyDispatchFilters` method entirely.

However, if the list of filters changes after bootstrapping, and you do need a dynamic factory method to return the available Filters to your constructors, then you may to resort to a [hack like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37470485).

Alternatively, if you don't have many classes dependent on the `IList<>` you can also explicitly register each class, which again takes precedence over the multi-injection, so the Bootstrapping code becomes:

```
kernel.Bind<ResolveMe>()
     .ToSelf()
     .WithConstructorArgument<IEnumerable<IDispatchFilter>>(bindDecoyDispatchFilters);

private IList<IDispatchFilter> bindDecoyDispatchFilters(IContext context)
{
    // Contract.Assert(1 == 0); // .. .ensure the method is called during resolution!
    context.Kernel.Bind<IDispatchFilter>().To<WindowsXpFilter>();
    return context.Kernel.GetAll<IDispatchFilter>().ToList();
}
```

The classes I used to test were:

```
public interface IDispatchFilter {}

public class WindowsXpFilter : IDispatchFilter { }

public class ResolveMe
{
    public IEnumerable<IDispatchFilter> Stuff { get; set; }

    public ResolveMe(IEnumerable<IDispatchFilter> stuff) { Stuff = stuff; }
}
```

And some tests:

```
  var y = kernel.Get<ResolveMe>();
  Assert.IsTrue(y.Stuff.Any());
```

Comment: IMO multi injection is quite cute, but the precedence of an explicitly registered `IList<T>` needs to take precedence over multi-injection.